# Submitting programmatically inserted value and registering for the auto complete feature

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I found that if you programmatically fill an input element with a value using javascript and subsequently press the button (without touching the input element), the value will not be registered with the auto complete feature in ie (testing with 6, 7, 8), whereas this does work in "normal" modern browsers. The values will only be added to the auto complete register if you manually press at least one key and subsequently press the submit button.

Is there any workaround to make older ie browser register programmatically inserted values? For example, is there a way to simulate typing the value that actually fills out this value in the input element?

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementsByName("test")[0];
    input.value = "some value";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. IE8 and his older brothers are, well, old and unsupported with newer frameworks due to these kind of problems.

Modern browsers will know to save the correct value, even if it was written through Javascript, since they write the real value of the input. IE8 and older save the value only if you have written it - there is no way to simulate a writing of the value as if the user would write it.

Comment: I later found that using a combination of the focus() function on the input element, firing an onkeypress event with an arbitrary keyCode on this element and using the click() method on a hidden button would do the job (populating the autocomplete register). These steps should be taken after the input has been given a value.

Comment: If you can write an example code for that, you should post that as an answer to yourself for future reference